# django ModelChoiceField: display field names

Tags: django, field, names, choicefield

I would like to display all the field names of a table in a drop down list. Here is my form:

```
sortFields=forms.ModelChoiceField(queryset=ActsInformationModel._meta.get_all_field_names(), empty_label="Select the sort field")
```

I get the error 'list' object has no attribute 'all'.

What's wrong?

Thanks in advance,

Romain

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need a [ChoiceField](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/ref/forms/fields/#choicefield) here:

```
choices = [(i, i) for i in ActsInformationModel._meta.get_all_field_names()]

sortFields = forms.ChoiceField(label='Sort',
                               choices=choices)
```